# python 21 card game problems

Tags: python

I'm working on a Blackjack/21 card game and I can't seem to get it to the third card added when I draw again. This also happens with the dealer, who just gets stuck in an endless loop of drawing a card, removing the previous card, than adding that card.

Sorry for the horrible format, I still don't know what I'm doing. (With this or Python)

```
import random

for deal in range(1,2):
  card1=random.randrange(1,12)
  card2=random.randrange(1,12)
  if card1 == 1 or card1 == 11:
    ace1 = int(input("Would you like a 1 or 11?"))
    if ace1 == 1:
      card1 = 1
    elif ace1 == 11:    
      card1 = 11
    else:
      print "not a choice. P.S. I'm too lazy/don't know how to loop this, so you better restart"
  print card1
  if card2 == 1 or card2 == 11:
    ace2 = int(input("Would you like a 1 or 11?"))
    if ace2 == 1:
      card2 = 1
    elif ace2 == 11:
      card2 = 11
    else:
      print "not a choice. P.S. I'm too lazy/don't know how to loop this, so you better restart"
  print card2
  hand = card1+card2
  if hand == 21:
    print "You win"
    print "You're hand is", hand
  elif hand > 21:
    print "You busted"
    print "You're hand is", hand
  else:
    print "You're hand is", hand
for deal in range(1,2):
  dealer_card1=random.randrange(1,12)
  dealer_card2=random.randrange(1,12)
  dealer_cards=dealer_card1 + dealer_card2
  print "The dealer has drawn his hand"
  if dealer_cards == 21:
    print "Dealer won"
  elif dealer_cards > 21:
    print "Dealer busted, you won"
  else:
    print "You're turn"
dealer_hand = [dealer_card1,dealer_card2]
player_hand = [card1,card2]

def draw():
  draw = input("Would you like to [H]it or [S]tay?")
  if draw == "h":
    card3 = random.randrange(1,12)
    if card3 == 1 or card3 == 11:
      ace3 = int(input("Would you like a 1 or 11?"))
      if ace3 == 1:
        card3 = 1
      elif ace3 == 11:
        card3 = 11
      else:
        print "not a choice. P.S. I'm too lazy/don't know how to loop this, so you better restart"
    print "You drew a", card3
    hand1 = hand + card3
    player_hand = [card1,card2,card3]
    print hand1
    if hand1 == 21:
      print "You won"
    elif hand1 > 21:
      print "You busted"
    elif hand1 > 15:
      print "So close"
      print "Dealer's turn"
      print dealerdraw()
    else:
      print "you've got a way to go"
      print "Dealer's turn"
      print dealerdraw()
  elif draw == "s":
    if hand >= 16:
      print "Nice play"
      print "Dealer's turn"
      print dealerdraw()
    elif hand == 21:
      print "You won"
    else:
      print "Not the best play"
      print "Dealer's turn"
      print dealerdraw()
  else:
    print "not a choice. P.S. I'm too lazy/don't know how to loop this, so you better restart"
  return " "

def dealerdraw():
  if dealer_cards < 21:
    dealer_card3 = random.randrange(1,12)
    dealer_hand = [dealer_card1,dealer_card2,dealer_card3]
    dealer_cards1 = dealer_cards + dealer_card3
    print "Dealer drew a card"
    if dealer_cards1 == 21:
      print "Dealer won"
      print "his hand was", dealer_hand, "totaling", dealer_cards1
    elif dealer_cards1 > 21:
      print "Dealer busted, you won"
      print "his hand was", dealer_hand, "totaling", dealer_cards1
    else:
      print "The Dealer smirks"
      print "You're turn"
      print draw()
  elif dealer_cards == 21:
    print "Dealer won, his hand was", dealer_hand, "totaling", dealer_cards1
  else:
    print "If you see this, the game isn't working"
  return " "
print draw()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the provided code, the `print`statements suggest that you are using python2, but the various `input()` calls seems to be python3.

I think you are using python2, otherwise the compiler will complain and will not print anything.

In this case, rewrite the inputs in pyhton2 style:

```
ace1 = int(input("Would you like a 1 or 11?"))
```

becomes:

```
ace1 = input("Would you like a 1 or 11?")
```

And similar the `ace2` and the `ace3` in the `draw` function. In python2, `input()` already evaluates the input, so you already get an integer if you input an integer.

```
draw = input("Would you like to [H]it or [S]tay?")
```

becomes:

```
draw = raw_input("Would you like to [H]it or [S]tay?")
```

Here is probably the problem. `input()` try to treat the string as a variable, which does not exist of course. In python2 you need `raw_input()` to take a string as input.

> This also happens with the dealer, who just gets stuck in an endless
>   loop of drawing a card, removing the previous card, than adding that
>   card.

I edited the `dealerdraw()` to solve this part:

```
def dealerdraw():
    global dealer_cards
    if dealer_cards < 21:
        dealer_card3 = random.randrange(1,12)
        dealer_hand.append(dealer_card3) #add the card to the dealer's list cards
        dealer_cards = sum(dealer_hand) #get the sum of all the cards
        print dealer_hand #just to show that cards in dealer hands are added, remove this line in real game
        print "Dealer drew a card"
        if dealer_cards == 21:
            print "Dealer won"
            print "his hand was", dealer_hand, "totaling", dealer_cards
        elif dealer_cards > 21:
            print "Dealer busted, you won"
            print "his hand was", dealer_hand, "totaling", dealer_cards
        else:
            print "The Dealer smirks"
            print "You're turn"
            print draw()
    elif dealer_cards == 21:
        print "Dealer won, his hand was", dealer_hand, "totaling", dealer_cards
    else:
        print "If you see this, the game isn't working"
    return " "
```

The dealer will always draw a card. But now all the cards in his hand are properly added, and or he wins by getting 21, or he bust. Up to you to improve the code and let the dealer stay.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. em that took a while but i think i finally got it working :)

```
import random

hand = 0

def draw():
  global hand
  hand = 0
  draw = input("Would you like to [H]it or [S]tay?")

  if draw == "h":

    card3 = random.randrange(1,12)

    if card3 == 1 or card3 == 11:

      ace3 = int(input("Would you like a 1 or 11?"))

      if ace3 == 1:

        card3 = 1

      elif ace3 == 11:

        card3 = 11

      else:

        print ("not a choice. P.S. I'm too lazy/don't know how to loop this, so you better restart")

    print ("You drew a", card3)

    hand1 = hand + card3

    player_hand = [card1,card2,card3]

    print (hand1)
    if hand1 == 21:

      print ("You won")


    elif hand1 > 21:

      print ("You busted")


    elif hand1 > 15:

      print ("So close")

      print ("Dealer's turn")

      print (dealerdraw())

    else:

      print ("you've got a way to go")

      print ("Dealer's turn")

      print (dealerdraw())

  elif draw == "s":

    if hand >= 16:

      print ("Nice play")

      print ("Dealer's turn")

      print (dealerdraw())

    elif hand == 21:

      print ("You won")

    else:

      print ("Not the best play")

      print ("Dealer's turn")

      print (dealerdraw())

  else:

    print ("not a choice. P.S. I'm too lazy/don't know how to loop this, so you better restart")



def dealerdraw():
  global dealer_cards
  global hand
  if dealer_cards < 21:

    dealer_card3 = random.randrange(1,12)

    dealer_cards += dealer_card3

    print (dealer_cards)
    dealer_cards1 = dealer_cards + dealer_card3

    print ("Dealer drew a card of", dealer_cards)

    if dealer_cards == 21:

      print ("Dealer won")

      print ("his hand was", dealer_hand, "totaling", dealer_cards1)


    elif dealer_cards > 21:

      print ("Dealer busted, you won")

      print ("his hand was", dealer_hand, "totaling", dealer_cards1)


    else:
      if hand > dealer_cards:
        print("you won")
      else: 
        print ("The Dealer won")

  elif dealer_cards == 21:

    print ("Dealer won, his hand was", dealer_hand, "totaling", dealer_cards1)

  else:

    print ("If you see this, the game isn't working")




while True:
    for deal in range(1,2):

      card1=random.randrange(1,12)

      card2=random.randrange(1,12)

      if card1 == 1 or card1 == 11:

        ace1 = int(input("Would you like a 1 or 11?"))

        if ace1 == 1:

          card1 = 1

        elif ace1 == 11:

          card1 = 11

        else:

          print ("not a choice. P.S. I'm too lazy/don't know how to loop this, so you better restart")

      print (card1)

      if card2 == 1 or card2 == 11:

        ace2 = int(input("Would you like a 1 or 11?"))

        if ace2 == 1:

          card2 = 1

        elif ace2 == 11:

          card2 = 11

        else:

          print ("not a choice. P.S. I'm too lazy/don't know how to loop this, so you better restart")

      print (card2)

      hand = card1+card2

      if hand > 21:

        print ("You busted")

        print ("You're hand is", hand)


      else:

        print ("You're hand is", hand)


    for deal in range(1,2):

      dealer_card1=random.randrange(1,12)

      dealer_card2=random.randrange(1,12)

      dealer_cards=dealer_card1 + dealer_card2

      print ("The dealer has drawn his hand of", dealer_cards)

      if dealer_cards == 21:

        print ("Dealer won")

      elif dealer_cards > 21:

        print ("Dealer busted, you won")


      else:

        print ("You're turn")

    dealer_hand = [dealer_card1,dealer_card2]

    player_hand = [card1,card2]



    draw()
    print("---NEW GAME---")
```

Comment: Well, there are some problems with it, numbers coming from nowhere, (I also don't need the dealer hand to be shown until the game is over) only the first two cards are showing. All I'm saying is it needs optimizing.